# How to go about this proof for non zero polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

How do I go about proving this?

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $X$ an indeterminate, and consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}[X]$.

> Let $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb{F}[X]$ with $f(X), g(X) \neq 0$.  Prove that $f(X)g(X) \neq 0$.

It seems pretty obvious but I'm not sure how exactly to write it down. I'm guessing since $f(X),g(X) \neq 0$ then the degree of both $f(X),g(X)$ are greater than or equal to zero so using the fact that $\deg(f(X)g(X))= \deg(f(X)) + \deg(g(X))$ the result follows.

Any help?

Comment: Please type your questions rather than uploading an image of the question since images are not searchable.

Answer (score 4):

You can see [here](http://planetmath.org/polynomialringoverintegraldomain) more generally:

Theorem.
If the coefficient ring $R$ is an integral domain, then so is also its polynomial ring $R[X]$.

Let $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ be two non-zero polynomials in $R[X]$ and let $a_f$ and $b_g$ be their leading coefficients, respectively.  Thus  $a_f≠0,  b_g≠0$,  and because $R$ has no zero divisors,  $a_fb_g≠0$.  But the product $a_fb_g$ is the leading coefficient of $f(X)g(X)$ and so $f(X)g(X)$ cannot be the zero polynomial.  Consequently, $R[X]$ has no zero divisors

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, whether this is necessary (meaning, that there is probably different more general approach - as shown in the other answer. But if we want to use the identity of the degrees we need to split it), but let's divide it into two cases. First when the degree of $f, g$ is $0$ and then else:

1. In the first case $\operatorname{deg}(f(x)) = 0$ and $\operatorname{deg}(g(x))=0$, so $f(x) = a, g(x) = b, a \neq 0 \neq b$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$, then $f(x)g(x) = ab \neq 0$. Done.
2. Now $\operatorname{deg}(f(x)) > 0$ and $\operatorname{deg}(g(x))>0$. For contradiction assume $f(x)g(x) = 0$, that means $-\infty =\operatorname{deg}(f(x)g(x)) = \operatorname{deg}(f(x)) + \operatorname{deg}(g(x)) > 0$. Absurd.

To be fair, we should also consider $\operatorname{deg}(f(x)) = 0, \operatorname{deg}(g(x)) >0$ (or vice versa). In that case $-\infty =\operatorname{deg}(f(x)g(x)) = \operatorname{deg}(f(x)) + \operatorname{deg}(g(x)) = 0 + \operatorname{deg}(g(x)) > 0$